# How to keep the camera rolling even after locking of desktop in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, video, lenovo-laptop, camera

My profession requires me to keep my laptop on at all times but there is problem. I have a maid who comes at 8:00 am in the morning and I will be asleep (pay attention here don’t ask me about the maid) so I have to keep the camera of my laptop rolling even after locking my system.

The question is, how do I do that? Is there any free software or any Windows feature to help me with that?

PS: I know you must be thinking in your mind that why don’t I just buy a CCTV camera? The answer is that I did, but I felt very conscious knowing there was a camera watching me behind my back, so yeah, I need an alternative to that.

Comment: “I have a maid who comes at 8:00 am in the morning […] so I have to keep the camera of my laptop rolling even after locking my system.” None of this sounds like a legit question. Makes no sense. Is the camera to monitor the maid for your “profession?” Seriously? I don’t believe any of this.

Comment: Don't like a camera behind your back? Put it somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting might still work in Windows 10.

To enable or disable the camera on your Lock Screen using the registry:

- Run `regedit`
- Navigate to:
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\AccessPage\Camera`
- Change the Value of the DWORD `CameraEnabled` to `1` to enable, or to
  `0` to disable.